# Understanding VimClojure new installation startup errors

Tags: vim, clojure, vimclojure

I am attempting to get vimclojure working for the first time. I am fairly new to vim plugins.  I'm having some problems (error messages below) and am looking for some hints at the least. Not much idea where to start.

I am trying to following the steps from [How I tamed VimClojure](http://blog.darevay.com/2010/10/how-i-tamed-vimclojure/) as well as inspecting [VimClojure-Easy](https://github.com/daveray/vimclojure-easy)

When I start vim, I am presented with the following error (occurs in both VimClojure 2.3.1 and 2.3.3, the later below):

```
Error detected while processing /home/nzucker/.vim/bundle/vimclojure/autoload/vimclojure.vim:
line  249:
E475: Invalid argument: 1
line  273:
E475: Invalid argument: 2
line  343:
E475: Invalid argument: 1
line  367:
E475: Invalid argument: 2
line  407:
E475: Invalid argument: 2
line  413:
E475: Invalid argument: 7
line  730:
E475: Invalid argument: 1
line  747:
E475: Invalid argument: 2
line  823:
E475: Invalid argument: 8
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

(First error location: [vimclojure.vim:249](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VimClojure/blob/da2683b9069e01c133f0c0129386fd6dc053019c/autoload/vimclojure.vim#L249))

The plugin seems to partially work however. I have syntax highlighting. When I attempt to open a REPL with the sr command, I get the following:

```
Error detected while processing function vimclojure#ProtectedPlug..vimclojure#ReportError..6..3:
line    1:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: _buffer
E15: Invalid expression: "buffer! " . self._buffer
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

For what it's worth my (ugly) `.vimrc` is here:
https://github.com/noahlz/dotfiles/commit/d0df9d0c5500e1803981b959c7fdbf88114000c6

Comment: Regarding vim, I just plunked the Clojure add in into my .vim directory (Ubuntu Linux). If comments are still allowed on that blog post, and you feel like commenting, I'd post that you have had a problem. Otherwise, I went with the Clojure vim plugin readme.

Comment: Which version of vim are you using? Maybe too old?

Comment: I'm on vim 7.0 / CentOS 5.5. Per the vimclojure download page, I switched to vimclojure 2.3.2 and got the same result.

Comment: For the record, vimclojure worked great with Ubuntu 12.04 and latest gvim 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please post this on the [vimclojure google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vimclojure). I'm not sure about what exactly the issue is. And this site is the wrong media to play questions back and forth.

Comment: For those who didn't click my link above, the answer is: "CentOS 5.5 and Vim 7.0 don't work. Upgrade."

Answer (score 1):

I was also unable to get it working following the blog post you referenced.  Once I started ignoring it totally and only followed the directions in vimclojure-easy, I was able to get it working.

Comment: The post is a little old and represents a much more involved setup. That's why it says "use vimclojure-easy" right at the top :)

Comment: vimclojure-easy didn't work either :( - I'm chalking this up to a combination of old vim version / CentOS.